# Are DDR3 rams OK for my motherboard?

Tags: memory, ddr3

I have a Gigabyte G31M-ES2L motherboard and Pentium(R) Dual-CoreE5500 2.80GHz processor.

I want to buy a DDR3 ram. Are my motherboard and processor suitable for DDR3 rams? If the answer is yes, how many Mhz should it be? For example is that one in the link below suitable for me? 
http://www.vatanbilgisayar.com/kingston-4gb-ddr3-1333mhz-cl9-pc-ram.html

Or what do you think that I should buy?

Tahnk you in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did some research and it looks like you can only use DDR2 1066(O.C.)/800/667 MHz memory modules. I consider you buying a new motherboard if you have the budget.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the budget for a motherboard right now. Is KINGSTON 2GB DDR2 800MHZ ok for me then?

Comment: @mrt It should be ok.

Comment: "I did some research and it looks like you can only use DDR2 1066(O.C.)/800/667 MHz memory modules. I consider you buying a new motherboard if you have the budget." - That is exactly what I said...